# Speed of different PHP mcrypt algorithms

Tags: php, performance, mcrypt

Hy guys. Today I was testing the php mcrypt algorithms.

I run a test to check the speed of different mcrypt algos.

**Tested algorithms:** *Cast-128, Gost, Rijndael-128, Twofish, Cast-256, Loki97, Rijndael-192, Saferplus, Blowfish-compat, Des, Rijndael-256, Serpent, Xtea, Blowfish, Rc2, Tripledes*.

The test was run in ECB mode (you also can use: *CBC, CFB, CTR, ECB, NCFB, NOFB, OFB*).

I encrypted a simple string: "This is a test". The following results are for 1000 iterations (results are in second).

> **BLOWFISH**
>   0.5217170715332
>
> **BLOWFISH COMPAT**
>   0.46304702758789
>
> **CAST 128**
>   0.19502091407776
>
> **CAST 256**
>   0.28649806976318
>
> **DES**
>   0.45267295837402
>
> **GOST**
>   0.19383502006531
>
> **LOKI97**
>   0.27537798881531
>
> **RC2**
>   0.44201898574829
>
> **RIJNDAEL 128**
>   0.2560601234436
>
> **RIJNDAEL 192**
>   0.33414602279663
>
> **RIJNDAEL 256**
>   0.42553782463074
>
> **SAFERPLUS**
>   0.32848501205444
>
> **SERPENT**
>   0.391037940979
>
> **TRIPLEDES**
>   0.65123796463013
>
> **TWOFISH**
>   0.27349305152893
>
> **XTEA**
>   0.37829685211182

Of course that process time is not the most important thing when we talk about security. I just want to share my results.

**What mcrypt algo and mode are you using, and why?**
I know that it depends on the situation, security level, etc. but give some examples please.

Comment: Good post, was searching the net for something like this... I wish I could find more performance stats, such as memory & cpu usage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) 256 (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`), why? Because of the algorithm notoriety and widespread usage. I'm also encrypting using `CBC` mode, I don't understand exactly the reason why but from what I read from various sources it's much more reliable (as in secure) than ECB.

Also, keep in mind that **when you're dealing with hashing and/or encryption speed is not your friend** (the reason for that is simple: **if it's fast, it's faster to crack**).

Comment: Yes, ECB is a very poor idea. ECB encrypts each block independently, making pattern analysis much easier. For a striking example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29

Comment: I've read quite a lot about AES/Rijndael in the past few days, so I thought I should note that here - Rijndael-256 is NOT AES-256. Only Rijndael-128 and AES-128 are interchangeable, because the IV size increases for stronger versions of Rijndael, while for AES it is always 16.

Comment: `MCRYPT_RIJNDEAL_256` is not AES.

Comment: Rijndeal-128 in CBC is same as AES-256 in CBC; i was just exchanging them yesterday (mcrypt to openssl migration), and their results are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is full test benchmark for speed comparison for **MCrypt versus OpenSSL** in PHP (symmetric cyphers):

- http://www.synet.sk/php/en/320-benchmarking-symmetric-cyphers-openssl-vs-mcrypt-in-php

[image: mcrypt vs. openSSL benchmark]

Mcrypt is older but better documented and significantly slower library, but very consistent output. OpenSSL is newer, faster and less documented.

If you care about performance in first place, then go with OpenSSL CFB/ECB 256-bit algo.

Note, that Intel Core i3/i5/i7 support **AES instruction set** that can extremly increase I/O throughput from 11 MB/sec to 700 MB/sec per thread - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard.

Comment: What PHP ver. is this?

Comment: @forsberg This was tested on PHP 5.5. some time ago. However, PHP version does not matter in this case, since encryption / decryption algorithm is what determines CPU cycles. Similar results would be achieved also with PHP 7. AES is generally much faster algo.